# Can you use direct composition with objects?

Tags: bitmap, directx, direct2d, direct3d11, direct-composition

I have found this tutorial [windows layering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn745861.aspx) and I would like to know if this is possible with 3d objects like in this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff729723.aspx). I would like to see only an object on transparent background. Thankyou.

Comment: Render object to texture with transparent background, blit texture into window.

Comment: what do you mean by "blit texture into window", I am using direct3d11

Comment: Well, that first tutorial basically covers everything. Instead of circle you can render cube or other3d object either directly on swap chain back buffer or using intermediate texture.

Comment: I am having this problem now "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758572/transparent-window-with-dwm"